# Can we have <!-- language-all: sql --> applied by default

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

I mean can we have `<!-- language-all: sql -->` applied by default to all posts where no highlighting is specified of course.

I note this would [make us different from the rest of SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting) [edit: or [possibly not](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5925108#5925108)], but on a site like this I think a SQL default makes sense.

The alternative is we go through and set the default highlight on every major tag.

Comment: I agree. Especially as it's clear that [we will have to update every new tag with the proper default language, even if it matches an existing pattern that *should* have an obvious default](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/136410/165455), e.g. when SQL Server 2015 comes out.

Comment: Although the markdown renderer doesn't have explicit MDX support I had to coerce the language to sql to get a snippet of MDX to render correctly

Comment: I like the idea! [Syntax highlighting language hints](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/981/169168) on SO-meta as a reference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've enabled this, but there are some caveats, so please keep them in mind:

- The default highlighting language is SQL. *NOT* auto-detect. If you ever want some other kind of syntax highlighting, you'll need to specify it explicitly (using the comment hint) or adjust the tag defaults accordingly.
- Syntax highlighting is enabled by default. So in places where you're using code blocks simply for the fixed-width spacing, you'll want to turn it off explicitly using the comment hint:

  ```
  <!-- language: lang-none -->
  ```

  or

  ```
  <!-- language-all: lang-none -->
  ```

Example: [Having multiple refs in an intersection table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17148/having-multiple-refs-in-an-intersection-table)

Comment: That's great, thanks!